# Referencing the id value from array and placing in a variable

Tags: php

I'm using CodeIgniter and I have a value that is being passed in my URL when I visit a page. The value that is passed is a string value, and there is an id that corresponds to that string in my database. Now I have a query in my model class that computes the string and returns it's respective id. This id I want to use for filtering my table.

View Class:

```
<?php  
$sessn=$this->session->userdata(); 
$status = $this->input->get('status');
$source = $this->input->get('source');
$content['getsource'] = $this->leads_model->get_selected_source($source)->result_array();
  $get_src = $content['getsource'];
  print_r($get_src);
$post = array('fstatus'=> $status,'fsource'=> $get_src);
$postd = json_encode(array_filter($post));
?>
```

Now here `print_r($get_src)` gives `Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 90 ) )`. Now I want to place this id field inside my `'fsource'=> $get_src`.

I've tried doing `'fsource'=> $get_src['id']` but this didn't work.

Comment: Of course that didn't work, because the only key on the top level is `0`. And the item that refers to, is in turn an array itself. So, obviously, `$get_src[0]['id']`.

Comment: @CBroe got it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 0 as a key in array so try like:

```
'fsource'=> $get_src[0]['id']
```